# Every two days Windows Domain removes my administrative privileges

Tags: windows, active-directory

My computer, running Windows 7 professional, is on a domain.

I have to change my account to set it administrative privileges every two weeks. I don't know why, every two days, my user is remove from PC's administrators group and another domain's user is set in my pc's administrators group and mine is remove it.

Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: Talk to your AD admins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your local Administrators group is managed via Group Policy or some other scheduled script. Talk to your IT department.